# Composition и Aggregation c#

Tags: c#, классы

У меня есть задача построить приложение кафе. Есть классы: Dish,Menu,Order.
У класса блюда есть ингредиенты,код блюда,цена и имя. У класса меню список блюд.
А у класса заказ все что должно быть, блюда не должно создаваться но должны использоваться,конструктор заполняющийся списком блюд.Я изучал про агрегации и композиции, но тут по-другому как-то.Именно как в этом примере использовать?
Вопрос: Где тут  использовать агрегацию и композицию? Зная то что в меню создается лист класса Dish, а что должно быть в order? И какой класс в main методе вызывать?